# Есть ли в Windows стандартные средства, похожие на Tshark или Tcpdump?

Tags: windows, сеть, tcp, wireshark

**Добрый день!**

Необходимо знать, есть ли в Windows что-то стандартное, что позволяло бы создавать дампы сетевого трафика( .pcap файлы )? Этим функционалом обладают нештатные WireShark( TShark ) и TcpDump.

**Спасибо!**

Comment: Что значит "штатные" и "нештатные"? (а tcpdump в unix-like'ах -- он штатный или нет?)

Comment: Штатный, в смысле, что идет по-умолчанию. Получается, что в никсах, да, штатный.

Answer (score 2):

Встроенных в систему нет, но есть [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) и его наследник [Message Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226). `tcpdump`, кстати, идет по умолчанию далеко не везде, надо ставить отдельно из пакетов.

Ссылки по Message Analyzer:

- [Meet the successor to Microsoft Network Monitor!](http://blogs.technet.com/b/messageanalyzer/archive/2012/09/17/meet-the-successor-to-microsoft-network-monitor.aspx)
- [All things about Message Analyzer and related diagnosis for Networks, Log files, and Windows Components](http://blogs.technet.com/b/messageanalyzer/)
- [Microsoft Message Analyzer Operating Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649776.aspx)